# How to calculate $\lim_{x\searrow 0}f'(x)$, where $f(x)=(\sin x)^{\cos x} + (\cos x)^{\sin x}$, without Taylor series or aproximations

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

> Let $f:[0, \frac{\pi}{2})\to\mathbb{R},\ f(x)=(\sin x)^{\cos x} + (\cos x)^{\sin x}$. Calculate $f'_d(0)$, the limit of the derivative in $x=0$.

I've seen this limit being computed before on this site, however never without aproximating $\cos x$ and $\sin x$, and I'm not quite able to do it myself. Here's what I tried:

$$\lim_{x\searrow 0}f'(x) = \lim_{x\searrow 0} (\sin x)^{\cos x}(-\sin(x)\ln(\sin x) + \cos(x)\cdot \frac{1}{\sin x} \cdot \cos x) + \underbrace{(\cos x)^{\sin x}}_{=1^0 = 1}(\underbrace{\cos(x)\ln(\cos x)}_{=1\cdot ln(1) = 0} - \underbrace{\sin(x)\cdot\frac{1}{\cos x}\cdot \sin x}_{=0}) = \\\ = \lim_{x\searrow 0} (\sin x)^{\cos x}(-\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\cdot x \cdot \ln(\frac{\sin x}{x} \cdot x) + \cos(x)\cdot \frac{1}{\frac{\sin x}{x}\cdot x} \cdot \cos (x)) = \lim_{x\searrow 0} (\sin x)^{\cos x}(-x\ln(x)+\frac{(\cos x)^2}{x})$$

From here, I'm not quite sure how to proceed. I'm not sure if I'm allowed to apply L'Hopital for $-x\ln(x)$ (because, if there were no parantheses, it would be multiplied by another term that contains $x$), and even if I can (I would appreciate if anyone could confirm this), I'm still not sure to continue (not without Taylor series anyway, because we haven't studied those yet). Any help or hints are much appreciated!

Comment: What's wrong with using "approximations"? So long as you're rigorous about it, this is fine and very useful

Comment: Use the most basic approximations. Otherwise, life will be difficult

Comment: There's nothing wrong with them, and I'm always impressed when I see people use them, but we've never been taught in class such techniques, and they're quite intimidating (especially Taylor and Maclaurin series), so I'm trying to understand how to solve limits without using approximations.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Do you happen to know a place from where I could read a few useful approximations? Not having learned this, I'm not quite sure I would know which ones to pick to remember.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to evaluate
$$\lim_{x\to 0}(\sin x)^{\cos x}(-\sin(x)\ln(\sin x) + \cos^2(x)/\sin x).$$

Note the first term in parenthesis vanishes in the limit since $t\ln t \to 0$ as $t\to 0$ (write  it as ${ \ln t \over 1/t}$ and apply L'Hôpital's rule). Thus, the limit is
$$\lim_{x\to 0}(\sin x)^{\cos x}(\cos^2(x)/\sin x)=\lim_{x\to 0}(\sin x)^{\cos x-1}\cos^2(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}(\sin x)^{\cos x-1},$$

and since
$$L:=\lim_{x\to 0}(\sin x)^{\cos x-1}=\exp\left\{\lim_{x\to 0}{\ln(\sin x)\over (\cos x-1)^{-1}}\right\},$$

applying L'Hôpital's rule and using the Pythagorean identity gives

$$\small L=\exp\left\{\lim_{x\to 0}{\cos x/\sin x\over (\cos x-1)^{-2}\sin x}\right\}=\exp\left\{\lim_{x\to 0}{\cos x(\cos x-1)^2 \over 1-\cos^2 x}\right\}=\exp\left\{\lim_{x\to 0}-{\cos x(\cos x-1) \over 1+\cos x}\right\}=1.$$